# Detect if UDP or TCP is enabled on webapp

Tags: javascript, tcp, udp

How can I check if udp and tcp are enabled in my webapplication, I guess I would Need to check this using JavaScript, but I have no real idea of where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking exactly? Could you further elaborate your question?

TCP and UDP are standard networking protocols and they are very unlikely to be disabled. When you are make AJAX requests using the standard APIs the browser will most likely use HTTP which sits on top of TCP (though there are some Google protocols that might work different). But this is besides the point, you do not have to worry about these underlying protocols unless you are doing something really complicated.